# How to add number to list in for loop?

Tags: python, list

Here, `H` is a list of integers.
As per the condition in a `for` loop, I want to add/subtract numbers to the list.

```
for i in range(len(H)):
    if H[i] > 43:
        d.append(int(int(H[i]) - int(33)))
        M.append(OVF(H[i]))
        #print H
    elif (H[i]) < -43:
        d.append(H[i] + 33)
        M.append(OVF(H[i]))         
    else:
        d.append(H)
```

I am getting error at `d.append(int(int(H[i]) - int(33)))`.

Please help, I am new to Python. The error I'm receiving is:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'.

Comment: What are `M` and `d` supposed to represent? Is `H` a list of integers, or is each element in `H` a list of integers?

Comment: NONE of those `int()`s appear necessary.  You claim `H` is an array of ints, `33` is an int already, subtraction of two ints is definitely an int.

Comment: Funny how you edited the post from `H[i]` being a list of integers to `H` being a list of integers. Now the error is no longer reproducable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote yourself that `H[i]` is a list and the error tells you that `int()` doesn't work with that kind of input, so I guess the error occurs when you call `int(H[i])`.
You can verify this with

```
>>> int([1., 2., 3.])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
>>> list(int(k) for k in [1., 2., 3.])
[1, 2, 3]
```

I guess you were expecting the output `[1, 2, 3]` with the call of `int([1., 2., 3.])` in the above example as you say you're new to Python. I think what you want instead is

```
d.append([int(h)-33 for h in H[i]])
```

**example:**

```
>>> d = []
>>> d.append([int(h)-33 for h in [1., 2., 3.]])
>>> d
[[-32, -31, -30]]
```

Comment: I applied the above command as per your suggestion but it gives me memory error, I could not understand what is wrong in it.

Comment: Moreover, I have a small doubt, the above command is applied in with in loop or outside the loop. Because in the H[i] list, when "if"   condition is satisfied then only, I have to add/subtract the int() value.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hist.py", line 195, in <module>
    d.append([int(h)-33 for h in H[i]])
MemoryError`